# eyecon robootstrap-datepicker - selecting all month

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I wanted to ask, if eyecon robootstrap-datepicker allows to select all month on simple button click (all days of current month)  ?

I don't see this option in API:
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Basicly, i just want to add event to some element on page (inside of datepicker i will prepend some element, Select all month ).

And this is done, but now i dont know, what action should i do to select all days from current opened datepicker.

[image]

Thanks for help.